# Heat equation with fourier transformation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I want to understand a solution from an exercise where we should find a solution of the heat equation:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x_j^2} $$ with $u(x,0)=f(x)\in L^1$.

The first step is to use the Fouriertransformation on both sides. But in order to get a ODE we must have the partial $\partial$ outside of the Fouriertransformation. How we can take it out?

Comment: Insert the expression $u(x,t) = \int\!dk\,e^{i k\cdot x} \hat u(k,t)$ into your differential equation.

Comment: As you can see, the common practice is to assume that the interchange can be justified, and it is done without much thought. The final solution is verified to hold under certain conditions. Even with the final solution in hand, it is often hard to justify the interchange after the fact. $C_0$ semigroup theory addresses these operations by looking at the map $t\mapsto u(x,t)$ as a vector map, and this theory does a good job of effectively justifying such operations. It seems to be the right point of view on the subject, and studying $t\mapsto \hat{u}(s,t)$ is a natural in this language.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want to show that for $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$ \mathscr{F} \left ( \frac{ d g }{dx} \right ) = i \xi \mathscr{F}( g ) $$
where the Fourier transform takes $\mathscr{F} : u(x) \to \hat u( \xi)$. Apply this to $\Delta u$ now to see
$$ \mathscr{F} ( \Delta u ) = - || \xi ||^2 \hat u $$
Since you'll take this as a spacial transform (not time), the time derivative will pass through the transform. i.e.
$$ \mathscr{F} (u_t ) = \hat u_t$$
Putting all the pieces together shows that the Fourier transform applied to the PDE gives
$$ \Delta u = u_t \to - | \xi|^2 \hat u = \hat u_t $$
i.e. an ODE in $t$.